# Array sort in php with multiple ways

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

i have two arrays for example
Array1:

```
Array(
    [id] => 50575
    [name] => Funbox - Pirates and Princesses
    [venue_id] => 3248
)
```

Array2:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 53295
            [name] => Funbox - Pirates and Princesses
            [venue_id] => 2954
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 53323
            [name] => Funbox - Pirates and Princesses
            [venue_id] => 2954
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 53391
            [name] => Funbox - Pirates and Princesses
            [venue_id] => 2954
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 53402
            [name] => Funbox - Pirates and Princesses
            [venue_id] => 2954
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 57130
            [name] => Funbox - Pirates and Princesses
            [venue_id] => 2980
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 57142
            [name] => Funbox - Pirates and Princesses
            [venue_id] => 3248
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [id] => 50575
            [name] => Funbox - Pirates and Princesses
            [venue_id] => 3248
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [id] => 50601
            [name] => Funbox - Pirates and Princesses
            [venue_id] => 3248
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [id] => 56113
            [name] => Funbox - Pirates and Princesses
            [venue_id] => 2882
        )
)
```

the array 1 will be any one sub array from array 2,

now i want that in array 2 the first array should be that one which is array 1, after that those sub arrays which have venue id same as array 1 venue id should exist and then all other arrays.
how to do this sorting?
sorry if any english error i m not good in that.

expected output:

```
Array
    (
        [6] => Array
            (
                [id] => 50575
                [name] => Funbox - Pirates and Princesses
                [venue_id] => 3248
            )
        [5] => Array
            (
                [id] => 57142
                [name] => Funbox - Pirates and Princesses
                [venue_id] => 3248
            )
        [7] => Array
            (
                [id] => 50601
                [name] => Funbox - Pirates and Princesses
                [venue_id] => 3248
            )
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 53295
                [name] => Funbox - Pirates and Princesses
                [venue_id] => 2954
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 53323
                [name] => Funbox - Pirates and Princesses
                [venue_id] => 2954
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [id] => 53391
                [name] => Funbox - Pirates and Princesses
                [venue_id] => 2954
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [id] => 53402
                [name] => Funbox - Pirates and Princesses
                [venue_id] => 2954
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [id] => 57130
                [name] => Funbox - Pirates and Princesses
                [venue_id] => 2980
            )
        [8] => Array
            (
                [id] => 56113
                [name] => Funbox - Pirates and Princesses
                [venue_id] => 2882
            )
    )
```

Comment: Please show an example how the expected result should be.

Comment: `now i want that in array 2 the first array should be that one which is array 1, after that those sub arrays which have venue id same as array 1 venue id should exist and then all other arrays.` Didn't get that..

Comment: Please edit your question with expected output.

Comment: Post your expected output also?

Comment: wait i am doing that

Comment: segregate the values that matches in the first one, sort that, then sort the remaining second then merge

Comment: @ImranQamer You have been provided some answers. Give some feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort it to your example order using [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php).

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
  return $b["venue_id"] - $a["venue_id"];
}

usort($array2,"cmp");
```

All this does is sort descending by venue_id. So all arrays with the same venue_id will be grouped, with the highest venue_id at the top. It is a bit unclear from your answer if you wanted something else.

Edit: I have given this a bit more thought and come up with a function that should do what I *think* you're asking for. It's not perfect, but it should work.

```
function customSort($array1,$array2) {
    global $primaryVenue_id;
    $primaryVenue_id = $array1["venue_id"];
    function cmp($a, $b) {
        global $primaryVenue_id;
        if ($a["venue_id"] == $primaryVenue_id) return -1;
        elseif ($b["venue_id"] == $primaryVenue_id) return 1;
        else return $b["venue_id"] - $a["venue_id"];
    }

    usort($array2, "cmp");

    unset($primaryVenue_id);

    return $array2;
}
```

Basically if you call the function customSort($array1,$array2) then it will return *$array2*, with all subarrays containing the same venue_id as *$array1* first, followed by the rest descending order of id.

Answer (score 2):

This is a custom function should do what do you want:

```
 function sortArr($haystack, $needle){
        $out = array();

        foreach ($haystack as $index => $arr){
            if ($arr == $needle){
                $out["$index"] = $arr;
                unset ($haystack[$index]);
                break;
            } 
        }
        foreach ($haystack as $index => $arr){
            if ($arr['venue_id'] == $needle['venue_id']){
                $out["$index"] = $arr;
                unset($haystack[$index]);
            }
        }
        if (is_array($haystack)){
            return array_merge($out,$haystack);
        }

    }
```

The following is a [DEMO LINK](http://ideone.com/s6coqy)

Answer (score 1):

You can unset matching element from second array and than use [function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php) `array_unshift($array, $element);` to preppend array.

```
$needle = array(
  'id' => 50575,
  'name' => 'Funbox - Pirates and Princesses',
  'venue_id' => 3248
);

$stack = array(
  [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 53295
            [name] => Funbox - Pirates and Princesses
            [venue_id] => 2954
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 53323
            [name] => Funbox - Pirates and Princesses
            [venue_id] => 2954
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 53391
            [name] => Funbox - Pirates and Princesses
            [venue_id] => 2954
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 53402
            [name] => Funbox - Pirates and Princesses
            [venue_id] => 2954
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 57130
            [name] => Funbox - Pirates and Princesses
            [venue_id] => 2980
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 57142
            [name] => Funbox - Pirates and Princesses
            [venue_id] => 3248
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [id] => 50575
            [name] => Funbox - Pirates and Princesses
            [venue_id] => 3248
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [id] => 50601
            [name] => Funbox - Pirates and Princesses
            [venue_id] => 3248
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [id] => 56113
            [name] => Funbox - Pirates and Princesses
            [venue_id] => 2882
        )
);

foreach ($stack as $k => $v) {
  if ($v['id'] == $needle['id']) {
    unset($stack[$k]);
    array_unshift($stack, $needle);
    break;
  } else {
    //echo 'No matching element in existing array.';
  }
}
print_r($testArray);
```

output will be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 50575
            [name] => Funbox - Pirates and Princesses
            [venue_id] => 3248
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 53295
            [name] => Funbox - Pirates and Princesses
            [venue_id] => 2954
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 53323
            [name] => Funbox - Pirates and Princesses
            [venue_id] => 2954
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 53391
            [name] => Funbox - Pirates and Princesses
            [venue_id] => 2954
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 53402
            [name] => Funbox - Pirates and Princesses
            [venue_id] => 2954
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 57130
            [name] => Funbox - Pirates and Princesses
            [venue_id] => 2980
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [id] => 57142
            [name] => Funbox - Pirates and Princesses
            [venue_id] => 3248
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [id] => 50601
            [name] => Funbox - Pirates and Princesses
            [venue_id] => 3248
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [id] => 56113
            [name] => Funbox - Pirates and Princesses
            [venue_id] => 2882
        )

)
```

Comment: I just copied your output code. You need to wrap array keys and values with quotes if strings. Similar to what I did with `$needle`. `$stack` should looks like that too. If so, what is the error?